# Over payment by previous employer

Tags: salary

Hi I have received a letter this morning from my previous employer whom I ceased working for in May 2015.  They are stating that they over paid me by £124.01 and that they want it repaid.  I have no payslips or indication as to when this over payment happened.  What are my rights? Do I have to pay it back? Incidentally the employer was a bank.

Comment: No I don't believe they did overpay me in fact when I left they made a complete mess of my salary and then took loads back off me out of my holiday pay and pension never issuing a payslip even though I requested one. I will be asking for evidence obviously but I just wondered if they can legally ask for this money such a long time after they claim the mistake was made?

Comment: It's a question better asked on law.stackexchange.com, but in many places they have 6 years time. And often there are exceptions when being overpaid and having to pay it back is damaging for you (someone reported a case where a person was incorrectly paid money, therefore didn't get state benefits, and was asked to return the money and had lost their rights to the state benefits - no money returned even if it was 100% incorrectly paid, because of the damage this would have caused).

Comment: Obviously just because they claim they overpaid doesn't mean they did overpay. So you should respond that you don't believe you owe them anything, but since apparently they want all payments to be calculated correctly, you would like to receive a copy of all documents that led to their calculation that you owe them money.